# How to reload let's encrypt in nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, lets-encrypt

I'm using Let's encrypt to generate https certificate. This certificate is for 3 months.

The certificate is specified in Nginx:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
```

The certificate is auto renew each 3 months. To reload in Nginx, I just type `service nginx reload`, connected as root. Maybe there is something better.

I've tried to auto reload it in Nginx, with `crontab -e` as root, I added:

```
0 4 * * * service nginx reload
```

But it does nothing :-( I do not understand what I'm doing wrong...

My server is on Debian